# iPhone: Adding a Done button within a pop up DatePicker frame

Tags: iphone, popup, datepicker

I pop up a DatePicker with the following.  Now I'm trying to add a Done button at the top of the pop up frame.

```
-(IBAction) contactBDayDatePicker{

NSLog(@"contactBDayDatePicker");

pickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
pickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

if (self.pickerView.superview == nil){

    [self.view.window addSubview: self.pickerView];

    // size up the picker view to our screen and compute the start/end frame origin for our slide up animation
    //
    // compute the start frame
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

    NSLog(@"screenRect %@",NSStringFromCGRect(screenRect));

    CGSize pickerSize = [self.pickerView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];

    NSLog(@"pickerSize %@",NSStringFromCGSize(pickerSize));

    CGRect startRect = CGRectMake(0.0,
                                  screenRect.origin.y + screenRect.size.height,
                                  pickerSize.width, pickerSize.height);
    self.pickerView.frame = startRect;

    NSLog(@"pickerView.frame %@",NSStringFromCGRect(startRect));

    // compute the end frame
    CGRect pickerRect = CGRectMake(0.0,
                                   screenRect.origin.y + screenRect.size.height - pickerSize.height,
                                   pickerSize.width,
                                   pickerSize.height+10);

    NSLog(@"pickerRect %@",NSStringFromCGRect(pickerRect));

    // start the slide up animation
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

    // we need to perform some post operations after the animation is complete
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

    self.pickerView.frame = pickerRect;

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

 }
```

I have tried increasing the frame size by 10 points (see CGSize pickerSize above) and thought I could use something like the following, but the button refuses to display, plus I'm not sure how to place the button inside the pickerSize frame itself.  (BTW) The DatePicker and Button are overlaying a scrollView if that matters.

```
  UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
  [button setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  button.center = CGPointMake(160,240);
  [button addTarget:self action:@selector(done)    forControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchUpInside)];
  [self.view addSubview:button];
```

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need a button ? Could you specify that ? You could just make the result display without a button.

Comment: I believe that my answer on this question is a more elegant solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22768513/1631695.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've done basically the exact same thing.  I subclassed UIView.  It animates up and everything.  Here's some code for you:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#define MyDateTimePickerHeight 260

@interface MyDateTimePicker : UIView {
}

@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) UIDatePicker *picker;

- (void) setMode: (UIDatePickerMode) mode;
- (void) setHidden: (BOOL) hidden animated: (BOOL) animated;
- (void) addTargetForDoneButton: (id) target action: (SEL) action;

@end


#define MyDateTimePickerPickerHeight 216
#define MyDateTimePickerToolbarHeight 44

@interface MyDateTimePicker() 

@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) UIDatePicker *picker;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGRect originalFrame;

@property (nonatomic, assign) id doneTarget;
@property (nonatomic, assign) SEL doneSelector;

- (void) donePressed;

@end


@implementation MyDateTimePicker

@synthesize picker = _picker;
@synthesize originalFrame = _originalFrame;

@synthesize doneTarget = _doneTarget;
@synthesize doneSelector = _doneSelector;

- (id) initWithFrame: (CGRect) frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame: frame])) {
        self.originalFrame = frame;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        CGFloat width = self.bounds.size.width;
        UIDatePicker *picker = [[[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, MyDateTimePickerPickerHeight)] autorelease];
        [self addSubview: picker];

        UIToolbar *toolbar = [[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, MyDateTimePickerPickerHeight, width, MyDateTimePickerToolbarHeight)] autorelease];
        toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

        UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Done" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: self action: @selector(donePressed)] autorelease];
        doneButton.width = width - 20;
        toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObject: doneButton];
        [self addSubview: toolbar];

        self.picker = picker;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void) setMode: (UIDatePickerMode) mode {
    self.picker.datePickerMode = mode;
}

- (void) donePressed {
    if (self.doneTarget) {
        [self.doneTarget performSelector: self.doneSelector];
    }
}

- (void) addTargetForDoneButton: (id) target action: (SEL) action {
    self.doneTarget = target;
    self.doneSelector = action;
}

- (void) setHidden: (BOOL) hidden animated: (BOOL) animated {
    CGRect newFrame = self.originalFrame;
    newFrame.origin.y += hidden ? MyDateTimePickerHeight : 0;
    if (animated) {
        [UIView beginAnimations: @"animateDateTimePicker" context: nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration: MyConstantsElementAnimationLength];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

        self.frame = newFrame;      

        [UIView commitAnimations]; 
    } else {
        self.frame = newFrame;      
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: What's your value for "MyConstantsElementAnimationLength"

Comment: @yourfriendzak I think Apple uses a value close to 0.3 for most of their animations like this.  I use that value.

Answer (score 5):

I customize Micah's class to support multiple orientation and ARC

DateTimePicker.h

```
    @interface DateTimePicker : UIView {
}

@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) UIDatePicker *picker;

- (void) setMode: (UIDatePickerMode) mode;
- (void) addTargetForDoneButton: (id) target action: (SEL) action;

@end
```

DateTimePicker.m

```
#define MyDateTimePickerToolbarHeight 40

@interface DateTimePicker()

@property (nonatomic, assign, readwrite) UIDatePicker *picker;

@property (nonatomic, assign) id doneTarget;
@property (nonatomic, assign) SEL doneSelector;

- (void) donePressed;

@end


@implementation DateTimePicker

@synthesize picker = _picker;

@synthesize doneTarget = _doneTarget;
@synthesize doneSelector = _doneSelector;

- (id) initWithFrame: (CGRect) frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame: frame])) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        UIDatePicker *picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, MyDateTimePickerToolbarHeight, frame.size.width, frame.size.height - MyDateTimePickerToolbarHeight)];
        [self addSubview: picker];

        UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, MyDateTimePickerToolbarHeight)];
        toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
        toolbar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

        UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Done" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: self action: @selector(donePressed)];
        UIBarButtonItem* flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
        toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpace, doneButton, nil];

        [self addSubview: toolbar];

        self.picker = picker;
        picker.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;

        self.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
        self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) setMode: (UIDatePickerMode) mode {
    self.picker.datePickerMode = mode;
}

- (void) donePressed {
    if (self.doneTarget) {
        [self.doneTarget performSelector:self.doneSelector withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
    }
}

- (void) addTargetForDoneButton: (id) target action: (SEL) action {
    self.doneTarget = target;
    self.doneSelector = action;
}
```

Using custom view in your view controller:

```
NSDate *selectedDate;  
UIButton *button;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    selectedDate = [NSDate new];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy";

    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(buttonPressed:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [button setTitle:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:selectedDate] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 50, 100, 40.0);
    [self.view addSubview:button];

    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
    picker = [[DateTimePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, screenHeight/2 - 35, screenWidth, screenHeight/2 + 35)];
    [picker addTargetForDoneButton:self action:@selector(donePressed)];
    [self.view addSubview:picker];
    picker.hidden = YES;
    [picker setMode:UIDatePickerModeDate];
    [picker addTarget:self action:@selector(pickerChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

-(void)pickerChanged {  
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy";

    selectedDate = picker.date;
    [button setTitle:[dateFormatter stringFromDate:selectedDate] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}    

-(void)donePressed {
    picker.hidden = YES;
}

-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    picker.hidden = NO;
    [picker setDate:selectedDate]; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the work! I cannot seem to get the value? -( void) donePressed {
    NSDate *myDate = datePicker.date;
    NSLog(@"DATE: %@",myDate);
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm"];
    NSString *prettyVersion = [dateFormat stringFromDate:myDate];
    self.lblDateTime.text = prettyVersion;
    dtPicker.hidden = YES;
}………. Just returns NULL    Where datePicker equals your DateTimePicker *picker

Comment: Actually,  picker.date comes back as your class has no date property. So how do you get the info?

Comment: @Rick I updated my answer, let have a look. You need to have a selectedDate variable to keep date value. Let initialize with today value by selectedDate = [NSDate new];then set selectedDate to picker before it shows up. Besides, during pickerChanged event you need to update selectedDate value accordingly, I do update button title in this sample. So when done button is pressed, you have selectedDate value and then can submit a request to server or things like that. You might need another var to keep current date, in case users cancel selection, we can roll back to the current selected date.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time.  selectedDate = dtPicker.date; throws an error.  Property date not found on object of type DateTimePicker. I have picker as DateTimePicker *picker; in my .h file is this not correct?

Answer (score 4):

Example code using UIToolbar as accessoryview:

Define instance variables keyboardToolbar and datePicker.

```
if (keyboardToolbar == nil) {
    keyboardToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)];
    [keyboardToolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];

    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

    UIBarButtonItem *done = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(changeDate:)];

    [keyboardToolbar setItems:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: flexSpace, done, nil]];
}

self.userBirthdayTextField.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolbar;

if(datePicker == nil) {
    datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
}
self.userBirthdayTextField.inputView = datePicker;
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on above code, I made a repository on Git Hub:https://github.com/lenhhoxung86/CustomDatePicker

Comment: I don't know why people not accepted this answer. This is really nice solution. Thank you @lenhhoxung

Answer (score 2):

How about making a new UIView and put the datepicker and done button in it?