# How to add a UIToolbar on top of UIPickerView? (iPhone/iPad)

Tags: iphone, ipad, uipickerview, uitoolbar

In my app I have a button that when pressed should present a `UIPickerView` with a `UIToolbar` on top of it. When the user has selected the value in the `UIPickerView` they then press a button in the `UIToolbar` which dismisses both the `UIPickerView` and `UIToolbar`.

The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out a way to add the `UIToolbar` to the `UIPickerView`. Normally I would have a setup where a value in a `UITextField` is impacted by the selection in the `UIPickerView`. This way I can simply set the `UIToolbar` as the `inputAccessoryView`, however, this time round I don't have a `UITextField`.

Please can someone advise on how to add the `UIToolbar` on top of the `UIPickerView`?

Comment: I have made an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704592/objective-c-implementing-a-uipickerview-with-a-done-button/10705161#10705161

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best Solution for this is make use of `UIActionSheet`.

Just Create Global of `UIActionSheet`,add Your `UIToolbar` and  `UIPickerview` to `UIActionSheet` as subview.

At last add `UIActionSheet` in subview of your main View.

Hope It will help you.!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the toolbar to the parent container view of the UIPickerView. So if you know what that view is, then you can add the toolbar to that. If the container is a NavigationViewController you can add tools to it's toolbar.

If you don't have a parent view, then create one -- e.g., add a new view class -- give it a toolbar and add the PickerView under it in the same view.

To synchronize things in the interface, it is often easier to use NSNotifications:

In the picker view...

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"myParameterName", nil];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: myObject, nil];
NSDictionary *myDictionaryOfParameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects: objects forKeys: keys];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"myPickerViewChanged" object:nil userInfo: nil];
```

Then in the toolbar add an observer...

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(refreshView) name:@"myPickerViewChanged" object: nil];

//   ...

- (void) myPickerViewChanged: (NSNotification *) note  {
    NSDictionary * myDictionaryOfParameters = note.userInfo;
// Enable toolbar buttons, etc.
}
```

Hope this helps.