# UIButton in UIPickerview is not responding

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, uibutton, uipickerview

I have a custom view for row in UIPickerview as follow

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
  UIView *vw = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, pickerView.frame.size.width, 30)];
  UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, pickerView.frame.size.width, 30)];
  [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(filtercategory) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  btn.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
  [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"longmp"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [vw addSubview:btn];
  return vw;
}
```

The method `filtercategory` didn't get called. I searched for the solution. But can't get.

Even the `showsTouchWhenHighlighted` is not working.

The pickerview looks like

[image]

UiButton got added, since [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxDNi.png) is the plain white image, I tried different images to confirm.

How to make the UIButton to respond?

Comment: Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: @CW0007007, since the requirement is the user has to click the row after selecting the row.

Comment: Why though, this doesn't make sense to me. A picker view is just that, you pick the value and something happens. You don't pick a row then tap a button!!!! What if they miss tap and the row then scrolls to another as it should... You may want to rethink your approach in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
[btn setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

**Edit**

If you want user to select current item after scrolling to that item in UIPickerView then `UIActionSheet` can help you. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10784720/how-to-add-a-uitoolbar-on-top-of-uipickerview-iphone-ipad) can help you to add `UIToolBar` at top of `UIPickerView`.

You only need to add UIBarButtonItem in UIToolBar and It will look more natural to iOS users.

Comment: from where you called [pickerview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; ?

Comment: hi, does it fixed ?  I also face the problem... seem the UIPickerView is 'readonly' for row view,  it seem only allow use pick but input

Answer (score 1):

Make sure of two things:

1) It is not coming in this delegate function, since you want to handle your button click instead:

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

2) I have doubt on the button's frame here:

```
[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, pickerView.frame.size.width, 30)];
```

Make sure the button resides in the active area of the control. I have experience that if a control is outside the bounds of parent control it do not receive touches events.

3) Try with [UITapGestureRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355671/how-do-i-implement-the-uitapgesturerecognizer-into-my-application).

Comment: since the requirement is the user has to click the row after selecting the row. I can't use the didSelectRow method. and the button is come under view's frame. I can see the button's image within the view for row.

Comment: for the time being change the color of both button and uiview and don;t set image, then see if everything appears ant its position ?