# How to hide a UIPickerView when the user make its choice

Tags: iphone, xcode, hide, uipickerview

I've created a custom UIPickerView with the following code

```
UIPickerView *picker =[[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(139,50,161,30)];
    picker.delegate=self;
    picker.showsSelectionIndicator=YES;
    picker.hidden=NO;

    [self.view addSubview:picker];
```

Now I want to hide the pickerView when the user make its choice of a row simply with

```
picker.hidden=YES;
```

Now:
1) How can I recognize the choice of the user and then hide the unuseful pickerview?
2) Can I show the choice in a TextField? with @"choice"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using a UIPickerView as the inputView for a TextField (thus replacing the onscreen keyboard). I use the following delegate to dismiss the view.

```
#pragma mark - UIPickerViewDelegate
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    // Code logic
    [[self view] endEditing:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this line where you have created picker

```
picker.delegate = self;
```

your callback

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    picker.hidden=YES;
}
```

Comment: when I add this line: no visible @interface for 'UIPickerView' declares the selector "addTarget:action...' I've declared the picker in a function. How can I solve?

Comment: I've declared picker in the .h as a uipickerview and remove it from the function to do not hide the istance variable declared in .h, but he problem remains

Comment: @AlessandroBava Sorry was confused with date picker. Edited

Comment: and so itisn't possible to do that in this way?

Answer (score 2):

use the delegate method of `UIPickerView`     like bellow..

```
   - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

        yourTextField.text = [yourArray objectAtIndex:row];
        thePickerView.hidden = YES;

    }
```

Also you can take one `UIButton` and hide this with action event of `UIButton`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UINavigationBar and  Barbutton with cancel and Done text upon it.

You can refer the following link

[Objective C implementing a UIPickerView with a "Done" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704592/objective-c-implementing-a-uipickerview-with-a-done-button)

Comment: no, I don't want to add buttons to my view. I want to automatically hide when the user makes its choice :)

Comment: How will you recognise whether user selected the right selection or not?

Comment: just double tap on the selected row

Answer (score 0):

UIView *addMealView; // here i am showing my picker

```
   - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{   
[addMealView endEditing:YES];   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a UIPickerView as the inputView for a TextField (for replacing the standard keyboard). I use the ResignFirstResponder (TextField method)  to dismiss the view.

Answer (score 0):

In XCode 12.2 you could use:

```
thePickerView.isHidden = true
```