# Uipicker to replace Keyboard

Tags: xcode, replace, keyboard, uitextfield, uipicker

Ok I am trying to replace the Keyboard with the UIpicker. I got the code in, the Uipicker always show, and when you click on the text field of course the keyboard comes up....I even put break points in to see if it makes it to the code that tells it to hide the keyboard and it never does....Would someone look at it and see where i went wrong

```
 #import "collectionViewViewController.h"
#import "activityCell.h"

@interface collectionViewViewController ()
{
    NSArray *imageArray;
    NSArray *labelArray;
}

@end

@implementation collectionViewViewController
@synthesize pickerViewContainer;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //picker exists in the view, but is outside visible range
    UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 780, 400, 270)];
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:pickerView];



    [[self collectionView]setDataSource:self];
    [[self collectionView]setDelegate:self];

    imageArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:
        @"act_blank.png",
        @"act_blank.png",
       @"act_blank.png",
       @"act_blank.png",
       @"act_blank.png",
        @"act_blank.png",
        @"act_1.png",
        @"act_2.png",
        @"act_3.png",
        @"act_4.png",
        @"act_5.png",
        @"act_6.png",
        @"act_7.png",
        @"act_8.png",
        @"act_9.png",
        @"act_10.png",
        @"act_11.png",
        @"act_12.png",
        @"act_13.png",
        @"act_14.png",
        @"act_15.png",
        @"act_16.png",
        @"act_17.png",
        @"act_18.png",nil];

    [[self pickerView]setDataSource:self];
    [[self pickerView]setDelegate:self];


    arrayHour = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [arrayHour addObject:@"0 h"];
    [arrayHour addObject:@"1 h"];
    [arrayHour addObject:@"2 h"];
    [arrayHour addObject:@"3 h"];
    [arrayHour addObject:@"4 h"];
    [arrayHour addObject:@"5 h"];
    [arrayHour addObject:@"6 h"];
    [arrayHour addObject:@"7 h"];
    [arrayHour addObject:@"8 h"];

    arrayMinute = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [arrayMinute addObject:@"0 min"];
    [arrayMinute addObject:@"15 min"];
    [arrayMinute addObject:@"30 min"];
    [arrayMinute addObject:@"45 min"];
    pickerViewContainer.hidden = YES;


    //labelArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1st",@"2nd", nil];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

//animate the picker into view
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"picker" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

    _pickerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,-236);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

//animate the picker out of view
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"picker" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

    _pickerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,236);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

//just hide the keyboard in this example
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectioinView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [imageArray count];
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"cell";
    activityCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [[cell imageView]setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]]];

      UITextField *nameLabel = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:1];

    nameLabel.text = @"HERRO";
    //[[cell textField]setText:[labelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];

    return cell;




}



- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView
{

    return 2;

}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (component == HOUR)
        return [arrayHour count];
    if (component == Minutes)
        return [arrayMinute count];


    return 0;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{


    if (component == HOUR)
        return [arrayHour objectAtIndex:row];
    if (component == Minutes)
        return [arrayMinute objectAtIndex:row];


    return 0;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
//    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"cell";
//    
//    activityCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
//
//    
//    
//    UITextField *nameLabel = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:1];


    //nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %@",[arrayHour objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]], [arrayMinute objectAtIndex:[pickerView    selectedRowInComponent:1]]];


    //textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %@",[arrayHour objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]], [arrayMinute objectAtIndex:[pickerView    selectedRowInComponent:1]]];


    //[[cell textField]setText:[labelArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
    //textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@  %@",[arrayHour objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]], [arrayMinute objectAtIndex:[pickerView    selectedRowInComponent:1]]];


    return 0;
}




- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setCollectionView:nil];
    [self setPickerView:nil];
    [self setPickerViewContainer:nil];
    [self setTimeText:nil];
    collectionView = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
- (IBAction)closePicker:(id)sender {
    pickerViewContainer.hidden = YES;
}

- (IBAction)showPicker:(id)sender {
    pickerViewContainer.hidden = NO;
}
@end
```

THanks

Comment: It is not a good design pattern to let users tap text field first and then pick from `UIPickerView`. Text field is _redundant_ if is not used to receive keyboard inputs. Why not use a text-field like button to trigger picker view instead and set the title label of button to what user picks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not overriding the right delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    <code that presentes the picker view>
    return NO;
}
```

That should stop the text field from showing the keyboard, and instead do whatever you want.

Comment: Ok so what i need to do is '- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
     UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 780, 400, 270)];
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:pickerView];
    return NO;
}'

Comment: When i do this, it doesnt even call it...I place a break point on it...and it never acts on the code. Whether it is bool or void

Comment: Are you sure the text field's delegate is set to your view controller?

`textField.delegate = self`

I don't see it anywhere in your code. You can set it in Interface Builder, so I'm just double checking.

Comment: I do now, and still nothing, Let me add a small thing, that might make a small differance, I am using a collection view that has a textfield in it...If not no biggie....but i did find a small way to make the Uipicker to show up when touching the TextField, when you right click it, under sent events, where it says Editing Begins, Ctrl drag to the UIPicker and it will make the picker show up  now, but the Keyboard shows up as well, you just have to manually dismiss it..So if there is a small way to tell the Keybaord not to show up i think that would be good...Thanks

Comment: Are you getting a warning about "Assigning to 'id<UITextFieldDelegate>' from incompatible type <your class>'? That means you need to add it to the interface in the .h file with the other delegates you conform to. If you are doing that as well, you're sure the delegate is set, and you're not getting a callback, I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Ok I was getting a warning there, I did add it into the .h file and now that is gone, Along the way i found a few others that were not being called as well.BUT still the keybaord shows up...but it will pause for a bit

Answer (score 6):

Look at this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597902/bringing-up-a-uipickerview-rather-than-keyboard-input-ios/14613437#comment20594691_14613437) and my answer below, see if this helps. Basically the best way to handle this is to actually set the keyboard type to a UIPicker:

```
UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
pickerView.dataSource = self;
pickerView.delegate = self;
// ... ...
self.pickerTextField.inputView = pickerView;
```

Put this in your viewDidLoad or somewhere so that when the user selects the UITextField it actually pulls up a UIPicker instead.

Comment: An undiscovered gem of an answer!