# segue to a view from a tableview in different class

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uibutton, uistoryboardsegue

To explain the issue, I had `ViewControllerA` with a `UITableView` called `commentTableView` inside of it. and from `commentTableView` i would segue to `ViewControllerB` but I needed to add an addition `UITableView` called `mentionedFriendTable` to `ViewControllerA`. But once i did add `mentionFriendTable` I started to have issues with the tables that caused the app to crash.

**Issue Im Having**

I decided to place `commentTableView` into a different class called `justCommentsTable` which is a `UITableViewController class` and add that class to `ViewController`. I have to place `commentTableView` in a different class and not `mentionFriendTable` because `mentionFriendTable` needs to be in `ViewControllerA`. and after a couple of hours I finally got that to work. but now that segue I initially had to `ViewControllerB` does not work, and crashes saying

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<justCommentsTable: 0x21032160>) has no segue with identifier 'segueToViewControllerB'
```

**My Storyboard**

On my storyboard i have `ViewControllerA` with a `tableView` inside of it and i linked up the `tableview` to `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *commentTable;`
in the code below I explain how `commentTable` becomes the `tableview` from `justCommentsTable`

I know I'm getting this crash because `ViewControllerB` is connected to `ViewControllerA` through `MainStoryboard.storyboard` and not `justCommentsTable`

**My Question**

Is there a way to still segue `ViewControllerA` to `ViewControllerB` and pass data from `commentTableView` which is in a different class.

I'm gonna go ahead and place whatever code I find relevant to the issue. Just tell me if im missing any crucial code.

**ViewControllerA.h**

```
#import "justCommentsTable.h"

@interface ViewControllerA : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{


       // in justCommentsTable.m I add this controller to the view
            justCommentsTable *commentsController;


}


      //   this is the table that is link up in storyboard
        @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *commentTable;

      //this is my mentions table that needs to be in ViewControllerA
        @property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *mentionTableView;

@end
```

**ViewControllerA.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];

        **// i set up the mentionTable here**        

self.mentionTableView.transform = transform;
self.mentionTableView.delegate = self;
self.mentionTableView.dataSource = self;
self.mentionTableView.tag = 1;

[self.view addSubview:self.mentionTableView];

        **// i set up the commentTable here**        

if (commentsController == nil) {
        commentsController = [[justCommentsTable alloc] init];
    }


    [commentTable setDataSource:commentsController];
    [commentTable setDelegate:commentsController];
    [commentsController setHomeUserID:homeUserID];
    [commentsController setGetEventHostIDforNotif:getEventHostIDforNotif];
    [commentsController setGeteventIDfrSEgue:geteventIDfrSEgue];
    [commentsController setGetEVENTNamefrSegue:getEVENTNamefrSegue];

     **// i set commentsController to the Tableview in justCommentsTable class**        

            commentsController.view = commentsController.tableView;

}
```

**justCommentsTable.h**

```
@interface justCommentsTable : UITableViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,UITextFieldDelegate,UITextViewDelegate>

@end
```

**justCommentsTable.m**

```
@implementation justCommentsTable
   //buttonTag is used for a button on the customCells
int buttonTag;

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"commentCell";

    customCell *cell =(customCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[customCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    NSDictionary *commmentDict = [CommentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *commentText = [commmentDict objectForKey:@"comment"];


    cell.textLabel.text = commentText;

      // i need a custom button on the cells for other reasons
    [cell.cellButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showButtonIndex:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

 return cell;
}



-(void)showButtonIndex:(UIButton*)button{
    buttonTag = button.tag;
     /*
     buttonTag gets set here, and used in the prepareForSegue method
      to find out what row the button was on.
      */

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToViewControllerB" sender:self];

}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueToViewControllerB"]){
    //segue to profile from image button
    ViewControllerB *VCB = segue.destinationViewController;

    NSDictionary *commentDic = [CommentArray objectAtIndex:buttonTag];
     /*
          buttonTag was used to select the objectAtIndex
      */

   NSString *commentTitle = [commentDic objectForKey:@"comment_title"];

    VCB.title = commentTitle;
   }
}
```

I know where my issue is, I just have no idea on how to fix it. and Ive searched for problems like mine, but I cant find one with a solid answer. if anyone can help, it would greatly be appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Lets chat I think I can help you

Comment: @SamkitJain i actually never used the chat feature on stackoverflow, does it work off invites? if so, just invite me to a chatroom and i can explain my issue in more detail. thanks for responding by the way

Comment: Come here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/35469/samkit-jain?tab=access&highlight=1973339

Comment: Join this http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35469/samkit-jain