# Swift - Combining UITextfield inside UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

Does anybody know if this application is using UITableView and have a UITextView inside it? If so, i want to ask how this is done. I also was wondering how a single tap can present an datepicker. I've uploaded a picture for clarity of what i want to achieve.

[image]

Comment: There's no way to know by looking at that picture, but I would assume those are UILabels.  For tap/selection actions (such as showing a date picker on tap), look at `UITableViewDelegate` and its [tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614877-tableview) method.

Comment: If they are textfields, which i only assume since they keyboard is up, [set the inputView of textfield to a UIPickerView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14613437/5153744).

Answer (score 0):

It can be either a label or a text field. In terms of presenting a date picker, you would use the function didSelectRowAt like kid_x said. I did this on an app I'm building with the help of this site. First I declared `var datePickerVisible = false` in the ViewController Class

and using the picture as an example, I toggled the visibility of the Date Picker like so

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if indexPath.row == 1 {
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            datePickerVisible = !datePickerVisible
            tableView.endUpdates()
        }
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: It would help to write out the full code if you're going to submit an answer, such as writing out the full didSelectRow delegate method and using the indexPath within it