# Adding 'Done' or 'Search' button to iOS7 Safari date picker input type

Tags: html, ios7, mobile-safari

Is it possible to add a 'Done' button that will close the iOS Safari input date picker? Typically the user has to touch anywhere outside the picker to make it blur, and the user has the option to clear, but is it possible to add a button that blurs it? e.g. 'Done'. The default behavior is not obvious to some of my users.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone: Adding a Done button within a pop up DatePicker frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231587/iphone-adding-a-done-button-within-a-pop-up-datepicker-frame)

Comment: No it is not a dupe - the question is about html5  the link above is about ios native.