# NSUserDefaults is saving just last value

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

I have a problem if anyone can help me or can give me an advice whose who faced with similar problem. Ok, I save data in NSUsersDefaults like this

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:getDate];
[defaults setObject:data forKey:@"data"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

and now when I want to retrieve in this way:

```
NSData *theData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"data"];
NSString *date = (NSString *) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:theData];

if (date != nil) {
    NSMutableArray *mutable = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [mutable addObject:date];
}
```

is showing just last value, the value is picked from pickerDate. How can I make to save all dates that I'm picking from pickerDate. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: what is the type of getDate?

Comment: you should put the entire history (=dates) in an `NSMutableArray`, and you should save that into the `Documents` folder; and later you can restore it, extended it, erase it... or whatever you just could dream about.

Comment: getDate is type of NSString

Comment: Yes i put all history in a NSMutableArray but is storing just last value that I'm picking.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not using the `NSMutableDictionary` correctly. Look at this code:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:getDate];
[defaults setObject:data forKey:@"data"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

This means that you will always save the date under the key `data`. Because you're using a `NSString`, this means that if there is already an existing entry under `data`, it will overwrite it. For example:

The first time you use your app, there is nothing under `data` saved. I pick "1-20-2015", then my dictionary is:

{ data: "1-20-2015"}

Now I go and pick another date, "2-21-2015". I already have an entry under data, so this means it updates it to:

{ data: "2-21-2015"}

See how we erased "1-20-2015"? This is what's happening to you.

In a `Dictionary`, keys are unique objects. You need to use an `NSMutableArray` as the object, or use a unique key for each entry.

Comment: Thank you very you are right, is working but  I resolved this problem differently. I will post the answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

i dont think that is his problem. NSUSerdefaults can be used to store date- i have seen it being used right here in stack, that i have used too:

```
NSUserDefaults *dateData = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDate *selectedDate = [self.datePicker date];

[dateData setObject:selectedDate forKey:@"DatePickerViewController.selectedDate"];
```

and he is usingNSMutablearray- so that is not the problem either.
The problem is one of two:

1:
The problem could also be that the array is being initialised inside the loop, and previous values being saved in it are being deleted.

2:
i think the problem is the location where the code to save the data into the array is located.
I think you need to call the method to save the date into the array once the user is finished with selecting a date- the problem is that i dont think that datepicker has a delegate method that can know that the user has done so.

(

there is one that knows when any one field has been changed:

```
[self.myDatePicker addTarget:self
                      action:@selector(myAction:)
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

But this will not help you as this will be called every time a field is changed- that is: it will call once you change the month field, once when you change the day field and so on.

)

Maybe you can include a done button into the datepicker, and call a method that will store the date into the array when the user clicks on this button...

Comment: The second point that you mentioned here i think is correct but how to implement,  can you say to me how???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231587/iphone-adding-a-done-button-within-a-pop-up-datepicker-frame   and  http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/12/ios-uidatepicker-example-done-button.html will both help you do that.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me to find the answer. I will post the answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

Userdefaults is not for data storage. It is for user preferences. Somehow I think "all dates I'm picking from pickerDate" is not user preferences.

Instead of trying to store an `NSDate`, you can just store an `NSNumber` `@(date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)`. Makes it a lot easier.

And if you want to store more than one date - that's what an `NSArray` is there for.

Comment: Yes, you are right that UserDefaults is not for data storage, but I'm a lil bit confusing, can you develop your idea. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you saving date in NSdate formate and getting date in NSString.

Do like this

```
NSData *theData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"data"];
 NSDate *date =[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:theData];
```